# Gradle - Web Start Jar Signing

Tags: java, gradle

Currently I have a Gradle build for a Java Web Start Swing application that works. It's mainly using the steps outlined in: http://www.apprenticeshipnotes.org/2013/01/generating-webstart-files-using-gradle.html

The huge issue with doing a Gradle build this way, is that we are wasting time signing unchanging JARs every time we do a build (by far where most time is spent) in order to build the application.

I've been looking at Gradle code on Github, looking at other recipes that might point me in the right direction, but I can't seem to determine how I would go from a set of tasks that takes the build artifacts of an existing configuration, signs them, and then bundles them into the application to something that is much more efficient.

My idea was to have the ability to resolve dependencies, then determine if there was a 'signed' version of that dependency in the repository. If there was not a signed dependency, the build would sign that artifact and upload to a repository.

An easier approach that I was trying to take was a project that takes the runtime configuration of the application project and somehow loops over the dependencies and signs them and uploads the artifacts to a repo, but it's not clear to me how I could do this with the Configuration API. Just getting at the files of the configuration is not enough, because I would want dependency information for each JAR file.

It also gets a bit trickier with uploading the JARs, because if, for example, I upload a signed jar, say metrics-json-3.0.2.jar, as metrics-json-signed-3.0.2.jar, I would need to update the POM to reference the signed artifacts. Seems like there should be an easier approach

`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
        <name>Jackson Integration for Metrics</name>
        <packaging>bundle</packaging>
        <description>
            A set of Jackson modules which provide serializers for most Metrics classes.
        </description>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-healthchecks</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>`

Note, this is different from the signing mechanism provided by the existing Signing Plugin:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html